# Flow debug issue

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a screen flow in my testing org. that work fine in my testing org. so I depolyed the flow in to another  testing org in sales force. It is not working. an error message is displayed "Hmm, that didn't work. Check your internet connection and try again, or refresh the page. If the problem continues, ask your Salesforce admin to contact Salesforce Customer Support." I have check the log there no error catch in log all the elements are working fine.

Comment: Try opening the browser's console (often part of the developer tools/inspector) and look see if there are any reported errors in that. Please [edit] your question to add any details you find there.